# Checking each cell if value appears (pairwise checking)

Tags: libreoffice

I have a file in `LibreOffice calc` that looks like this:

```
CID/2D  70701913    70701915    70701916    70701903    59697911
70701913    1       0.738       0.688       0.396       0.416
70701915    0.738   1           0.862       0.489       0.52
70701916    0.688   0.862       1           0.495       0.526
70701903    0.396   0.489       0.495       1           0.914
59697354    0.416   0.511       0.526       0.87        0.95
59697683    0.416   0.511       0.526       0.87        0.95
59697583    0.381   0.459       0.472       0.887       0.81
59697533    0.4     0.486       0.5         0.81        0.878
11164341    0.4     0.478       0.5         0.772       0.836
59697614    0.4     0.478       0.5         0.772       0.836
70701907    0.366   0.437       0.449       0.817       0.745
70701904    0.383   0.462       0.474       0.745       0.803
70701905    0.383   0.454       0.474       0.712       0.766
70701906    0.383   0.454       0.474       0.712       0.766
70701901    0.379   0.466       0.479       0.885       0.806
```

I want check values when compare each row to each column and to keep only those cells that have number less then `0.4 (<0.4)`. So for example if I compare second row `70701913` to all columns, all columns within this row will be excluded except `70701903` because it has a value of `0.396` which is less then `0.4`. I have never done any programming in `LibreOffice calc`, so can anybody help me?

Comment: Cross-posted to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855513/pairwise-checking-of-the-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data in the question is on the sheet named `Sheet1` then add another sheet and enter the following in `Sheet2.B1`.

```
=IF(Sheet1.B2<0.4;Sheet1.B2;"")
```

Then drag to fill the formula down to F16.  Also, copy and paste the first row and first column, or in `Sheet2.A1` enter the following formula and drag to fill.

```
=Sheet1.A1
```

The result:

```
CID/2D      70701913    70701915    70701916    70701903    59697911
70701913                                        0.396   
70701915                    
70701916                    
70701903    0.396               
59697354                    
59697683                    
59697583    0.381               
59697533                    
11164341                    
59697614                    
70701907    0.366               
70701904    0.383               
70701905    0.383               
70701906    0.383               
70701901    0.379
```